# How to store the contents of a CSV file in a Linked List?

Tags: c, csv, file, linked-list, fopen

I am trying to insert the contents from a csv file into a linklist using C. However, I am getting quite a few garbage outputs. The source code is given below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
struct product *customer_head;

struct customer
{
    long long int c_id;//first 6 characters=date & next 6 characters=time & next characters=counter no & city code

    /*Compulsory Fields (Cannot be Skipped)*/
    char name[57];
    long long int ph_no;//10 digit phone number

    /*Non Compulsory Fields (Can be Skipped)*/
    char address[58];
    char city[25];
    char state_code[2];
    char pin[6];
    char email[60];

    struct customer *next;
};
struct customer * load()
{
    FILE * cust=fopen("customer_db.csv","r");
    struct customer *temp,*ptr;
    customer_head=NULL;
    char str[208];
    char *token,*eptr1,*eptr2;
    int line_cnt=0,i=0;

    while(fgets(str,234,cust)!=NULL)
    {
        line_cnt=0;
        i=0;
        ptr=(struct customer *)malloc(sizeof(struct customer));
        for(;str[i];i++)
        {
            if(str[i]=='\n')
            {
                str[i]='\0';
                i=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        token=strtok(str,",");

        while(token!=NULL)
        {

            if(line_cnt==0)
            ptr->c_id=strtoll(token,&eptr1,10);

            else if(line_cnt==1)
            ptr->ph_no=strtoll(token,&eptr2,10);

            else if(line_cnt==2)
            sprintf(ptr->name,"%s",token);

            else if(line_cnt==3)
            sprintf(ptr->address,"%s",token);

            else if(line_cnt==4)
            sprintf(ptr->city,"%s",token);

            else if(line_cnt==5)
            sprintf(ptr->state_code,"%s",token);

            else if(line_cnt==6)
            sprintf(ptr->pin,"%s",token);

            else
            sprintf(ptr->email,"%s",token);

            line_cnt++;

            token=strtok(NULL,",");

        }
        if(customer_head==NULL)
        customer_head=ptr;
        else
        temp->next=ptr;
        temp=ptr;


    }
}
int print(struct customer *h)
{

    while(h->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\nCustomer ID: ");
        printf("%lld",h->c_id);
        printf("\nName: ");
        puts(h->name);
        printf("Phone Number: ");
        printf("%lld",h->ph_no);
        printf("\nAddress: ");
        puts(h->address);
        printf("City: ");
        puts(h->city);
        printf("State Code: ");
        puts(h->state_code);
        printf("PIN: ");
        puts(h->pin);
        printf("Email: ");
        puts(h->email);
        h=h->next;
    }
        printf("\nCustomer ID: ");
        printf("%lld",h->c_id);
        printf("\nName: ");
        puts(h->name);
        printf("Phone Number: ");
        printf("%ld",h->ph_no);
        printf("\nAddress: ");
        puts(h->address);
        printf("City: ");
        puts(h->city);
        printf("State Code: ");
        puts(h->state_code);
        printf("PIN: ");
        puts(h->pin);
        printf("Email: ");
        puts(h->email);

    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    load();
    print(customer_head);
}
```

I am also attaching the csv file here. In order for the program to be less complicated I have removed the headings from my csv file. They are in the order

Customer_ID,Phone_Number,Name,Address,City,State_Code,PIN,Email

```
1403201156540201,2226179183,Katherine_Hamilton,87_Thompson_St.,Fremont,IA,502645,k_hamilton@gmail.com
2204201532220103,8023631298,Marc_Knight,-,-,-,-,-
0305201423120305,8025595163,Albie_Rowland,-,Hamburg,NY,140752,-
0607201232220901,4055218053,Grant_Phelps,-,-,-,-,-
```

The dashes(-) indicate that those fields should remain empty.

The output is as follows:

```
Customer ID: 1403201156540201
Name: Katherine_Hamilton
Phone Number: 2226179183
Address: 87_Thompson_St.
City: Fremont
State Code: IA502645k_hamilton@gmail.com
PIN: 502645k_hamilton@gmail.com
Email: k_hamilton@gmail.com

Customer ID: 2204201532220103
Name: Marc_Knight
Phone Number: 8023631298
Address: -
City: -
State Code: -
PIN: -
Email: -

Customer ID: 305201423120305
Name: Albie_Rowland
Phone Number: 8025595163
Address: -
City: Hamburg
State Code: NY140752-
PIN: 140752-
Email: -

Customer ID: 607201232220901
Name: Grant_Phelps
Phone Number: 4055218053
Address: -
City: -
State Code: -
PIN: -
Email: -
```

As you can see, the contents are getting merged in quite a few places. I don't understand why.

Comment: Your code indentation is suboptimal. You use `sprintf` all the time, which does not check boundaries and you don't check the result. At least use `snprintf`. Phone numbers are not integers and certainly not signed. The return value of your `load` function does not make sense, and you don't return anything anyway, so that's a compiler warning for you. At least fix some of that before continuing.

Comment: Empty values in a CSV file are usually indicated by not having any value present (`Albie_Rowland,,Hamburg`). Also, in case this is for production and not learning, you might want to use [libcsv](https://github.com/rgamble/libcsv).

Comment: Why are you using `sprintf`, e.g. `sprintf(ptr->address,"%s",token);` instead of `strcpy`?? And `printf("\nCustomer ID: ");` --> `fputs ("\nCustomer ID: ", stdout);` - there is no conversion required. (though a good compiler will make that optimization for you) No need for `str[i]='\0';` when using `strtok()`.

Comment: @Cheatah I agree, the return type of the `load` function doesn't make sense. I also changed `sprintf` to `snprintf` as it is more secure. Even after I made thus corrections, it still gives me unpredictable outputs. Also which data type should I use for phone numbers?

Comment: Return type of `struct customer * load()` makes *Perfect* sense. It allows you to declare `customer_head` local to `main()` and assign the return of `load()`. The only problem is `load()` should return `NULL` on failure or the last node (`temp`) on success, which is your head node due to your use of *forward-chaining* to fill your list. (which is why your list will be in reverse order to the data read from the file)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I could use `strcpy` . I tried to print the variables inside of the node while the values were being assigned. No matter whatever I use, be it `sprintf` or `snprintf` or `strcpy` , it prints the right thing. It somehow messes up whenever I try to print it using the `print` function.

Comment: You get garbage values, because e.g. `char state_code[2];` is 1 char ***too-short*** to hold a 2-character state code as a ***string***... the `'\0'` needs a character too. When you attempt to use it as a string, if it is not *nul-terminated* the *Undefined Behavior* results and all bets are off with your code from that point forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since from the comments you know that your declaration of your character arrays suffer from *one-too-few* character, at least in the case of `char state_code[2];` leaving your array without a *nul-terminating* character leading to *Undefined Behavior*, you should ensure you have valid storage for all your input. (don't skimp on buffer size)

In general, you are making things a bit harder on yourself than it needs to be. Rather than attempting to use `strtok()` and count field and handle each field in a 8-part chain of `if, else if ...`, you have fixed input fields, so just parse the data with `sscanf()` and validate the number of conversions to confirm a successful parse, e.g.

```
/** fill list from csv file */
list_t *list_from_csv (list_t *list, FILE *fp)
{
    char buf[MAXC];
    node_t data = { .c_id = 0, .next = NULL };

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line in file */
        /* parse and VALIDATE values from line */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%lld,%lld,%63[^,],%63[^,],%31[^,],%7[^,],%7[^,],%63[^,\n]",
                    &data.c_id, &data.ph_no, data.name, data.address, data.city,
                    data.state_code, data.pin, data.email) == 8) {
            if (!add (list, &data)) /* validate add to list or break */
                break;
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Here, `list_t` is just an additional "wrapper" struct that holds a `head` and `tail` pointer for your linked list. This allows you to declare multiple lists in the scope needed and allows the same O(1) insertion by having the `tail` pointer always point to the last node in your list (your `temp`). Here, `head` and `tail` are just part of the wrapper and passed as a parameter rather than having to declare the list-pointer as global (bad practice). Each of the nodes in your list and the wrapper struct can be written as:

```
#define BYTE8   8           /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define BYTE32 32
#define BYTE64 64
#define MAXC 1024

typedef struct node_t {     /* list node */
    /* 6 characters=date & 6 characters=time & counter no & city code */
    long long int c_id;

    /*Compulsory Fields (Cannot be Skipped)*/
    char name[BYTE64];
    long long int ph_no;    //10 digit phone number

    /*Non Compulsory Fields (Can be Skipped)*/
    char address[BYTE64];
    char city[BYTE32];
    char state_code[BYTE8];
    char pin[BYTE8];
    char email[BYTE64];

    struct node_t *next;
} node_t;

typedef struct {            /* list wrapper with head & tail pointers */
    node_t *head, *tail;
} list_t;
```

Then rather than writing your `load()` to contain both the `FILE` and list operations, keep your list operations separate. Simply create an `add()` function to add a node to your list, e.g.

```
/** add node at end of list, update tail to end */
node_t *add (list_t *l, node_t *data)
{
    node_t *node = malloc (sizeof *node);   /* allocate node */
    if (!node) {                            /* validate allocation */
        perror ("malloc-node");
        return NULL;
    }

    *node = *data;                      /* initialize members values */

    if (!l->head)                       /* if 1st node, node is head/tail */
        l->head = l->tail = node;
    else {                              /* otherwise */
        l->tail->next = node;           /* add at end, update tail pointer */
        l->tail = node;
    }

    return node;    /* return new node */
}
```

Now your load function need only read each line from the file and parse the line before calling `add()` passing a pointer to a struct of data along with the list pointer as parameters. Your `load()` function reduces to:

```
/** fill list from csv file */
list_t *list_from_csv (list_t *list, FILE *fp)
{
    char buf[MAXC];
    node_t data = { .c_id = 0, .next = NULL };

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line in file */
        /* parse and VALIDATE values from line */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%lld,%lld,%63[^,],%63[^,],%31[^,],%7[^,],%7[^,],%63[^,\n]",
                    &data.c_id, &data.ph_no, data.name, data.address, data.city,
                    data.state_code, data.pin, data.email) == 8) {
            if (!add (list, &data)) /* validate add to list or break */
                break;
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

(**note:** when using `strtok()` or `sscanf()`, there is no need to strip the trailing `'\n'` from your input string -- simply include that as a delimiter for `strtok()` or exclude it from the conversion with `sscanf()`)

Further, you don't need multiple calls to `puts()` and `printf()` to print each node's worth of data in your list. Look at how many function calls you make to print your data. You only need ONE call to `printf()`, e.g.

```
/** print all nodes in list */
void prn_list (list_t *l)
{
    if (!l->head) {
        puts ("list-empty");
        return;
    }

    for (node_t *n = l->head; n; n = n->next)
        printf ("\nCustomer ID: %lld\n"
                "Name: %s\n"
                "Phone Number: %lld\n"
                "Address: %s\n"
                "City: %s\n"
                "State Code: %s\n"
                "PIN: %s\n"
                "Email: %s\n", n->c_id, n->name, n->ph_no, n->address, n->city,
                                n->state_code, n->pin, n->email);
}
```

In `main()` simply declare an instance of your `list_t` wrapper, open/validate your `FILE` and then pass a pointer to the list and file-stream to your `list_from_csv()` (your `load()`) and then print the list and finally free all memory you have allocated and you are done. (yes, the memory will be freed on exit, but develop good habits early -- it won't be long before you are using allocate memory in function where a failure to free before `return` results in a *memory-leak*)

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    list_t list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!list_from_csv (&list, fp))
        return 1;

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    prn_list (&list);
    del_list (&list);
}
```

Putting it altogether, you would have something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BYTE8   8           /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define BYTE32 32
#define BYTE64 64
#define MAXC 1024

typedef struct node_t {     /* list node */
    /* 6 characters=date & 6 characters=time & counter no & city code */
    long long int c_id;

    /*Compulsory Fields (Cannot be Skipped)*/
    char name[BYTE64];
    long long int ph_no;    //10 digit phone number

    /*Non Compulsory Fields (Can be Skipped)*/
    char address[BYTE64];
    char city[BYTE32];
    char state_code[BYTE8];
    char pin[BYTE8];
    char email[BYTE64];

    struct node_t *next;
} node_t;

typedef struct {            /* list wrapper with head & tail pointers */
    node_t *head, *tail;
} list_t;


/** add node at end of list, update tail to end */
node_t *add (list_t *l, node_t *data)
{
    node_t *node = malloc (sizeof *node);   /* allocate node */
    if (!node) {                            /* validate allocation */
        perror ("malloc-node");
        return NULL;
    }

    *node = *data;                      /* initialize members values */

    if (!l->head)                       /* if 1st node, node is head/tail */
        l->head = l->tail = node;
    else {                              /* otherwise */
        l->tail->next = node;           /* add at end, update tail pointer */
        l->tail = node;
    }

    return node;    /* return new node */
}

/** print all nodes in list */
void prn_list (list_t *l)
{
    if (!l->head) {
        puts ("list-empty");
        return;
    }

    for (node_t *n = l->head; n; n = n->next)
        printf ("\nCustomer ID: %lld\n"
                "Name: %s\n"
                "Phone Number: %lld\n"
                "Address: %s\n"
                "City: %s\n"
                "State Code: %s\n"
                "PIN: %s\n"
                "Email: %s\n", n->c_id, n->name, n->ph_no, n->address, n->city,
                                n->state_code, n->pin, n->email);
}

/** delete all nodes in list */
void del_list (list_t *l)
{
    node_t *n = l->head;

    while (n) {
        node_t *victim = n;
        n = n->next;
        free (victim);
    }
}

/** fill list from csv file */
list_t *list_from_csv (list_t *list, FILE *fp)
{
    char buf[MAXC];
    node_t data = { .c_id = 0, .next = NULL };

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line in file */
        /* parse and VALIDATE values from line */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%lld,%lld,%63[^,],%63[^,],%31[^,],%7[^,],%7[^,],%63[^,\n]",
                    &data.c_id, &data.ph_no, data.name, data.address, data.city,
                    data.state_code, data.pin, data.email) == 8) {
            if (!add (list, &data)) /* validate add to list or break */
                break;
        }
    }

    return list;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    list_t list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!list_from_csv (&list, fp))
        return 1;

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    prn_list (&list);
    del_list (&list);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your input file in `dat/customer_list.txt`, running the program you would receive:

```
$ ./bin/customer_list dat/customer_list.txt

Customer ID: 1403201156540201
Name: Katherine_Hamilton
Phone Number: 2226179183
Address: 87_Thompson_St.
City: Fremont
State Code: IA
PIN: 502645
Email: k_hamilton@gmail.com

Customer ID: 2204201532220103
Name: Marc_Knight
Phone Number: 8023631298
Address: -
City: -
State Code: -
PIN: -
Email: -

Customer ID: 305201423120305
Name: Albie_Rowland
Phone Number: 8025595163
Address: -
City: Hamburg
State Code: NY
PIN: 140752
Email: -

Customer ID: 607201232220901
Name: Grant_Phelps
Phone Number: 4055218053
Address: -
City: -
State Code: -
PIN: -
Email: -
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/customer_list dat/customer_list.txt
==14823== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14823== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14823== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14823== Command: ./bin/customer_list dat/customer_list.txt
==14823==

Customer ID: 1403201156540201
Name: Katherine_Hamilton
Phone Number: 2226179183
Address: 87_Thompson_St.
City: Fremont
State Code: IA
PIN: 502645
Email: k_hamilton@gmail.com

<snipped rest>

==14823==
==14823== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14823==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14823==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 6,728 bytes allocated
==14823==
==14823== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==14823==
==14823== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14823== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

While you could cure a significant part of your problem just by ensuring you have adequate storage for each string, take the time to think through approaching the parse of values with `sscanf()` and since you control the conversion, there is no need to remove the trailing `'\n'` from the line read from the file. (just don't include the newline in the value parsed from your input string) If you did want to parse the `'\n'` from the end, you should be using, e.g.

```
    str[strcspn (str, "\n")] = 0;
```

Lastly with both the format-string used with `sscanf()` and with `strcspn()` above, make sure you understand exactly how they work, see [man 3 scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) and [man 3 strspn](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html)

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: That was quite a helpful explanation. I could understand a few of my mistakes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That was quite a helpful explanation. I could understand a few of my mistakes. Thanks a lot!
Could you just explain why you chose to declare these as global variables and not assign individual sizes ?
`#define BYTE8   8           
#define BYTE32 32
#define BYTE64 64
#define MAXC 1024`

Comment: Sure. Whenever you need a constant, you should `#define` them up top (or use a global `enum` for the same thing). That way if you need to adjust a constant later, you are not left picking through the body of your code to find every declaration or loop variable you must adjust. That way the comment says `/* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */`. Good luck with your coding! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
enum operations {EXIT, ADD_BOOK, ISSUE_BOOK, RETURN_BOOK, DISPLAY_BOOKS,
                SORT_BOOKS, DISPLAY_BOOK_SUBJECTWISE};
typedef enum operations MENU;
typedef struct book
{
    int bookId;
    char bookName[30];
    char subject[30];
    char author[30];
    float price;
}BOOK;
typedef struct node
{
    struct node *prev;
    BOOK info;
    struct node *next;
}NODE;
NODE *head=NULL;
NODE *issuehead=NULL;
static int counter=0;
MENU menu_function()
{
    int choice;
    printf(" 1. Add Book\n");
    printf(" 2. Issue Book\n");
    printf(" 3. Return Book\n");
    printf(" 4. Display Book\n");
    printf(" 5. Sort Book\n");
    printf(" 6. Display Books Subject-wise\n");
    printf(" 0. EXIT\n");
    printf(" Enter your choice::");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    if(choice < 0 || choice > 6)
    {
        printf(" Error: Enter valid choice\n");
    }
    return choice;
}
void FreeList()
{
    while(CountNodes(head))
    {
        DeleteBook();
    }
    while(CountNodes(issuehead))
    {
        DeleteIssues();
    }
}
int CountNodes(NODE *trav)
{
    int count=0;
    while(trav!=NULL)
    {
        count++;
        trav=trav->next;
    }
    return count;
}
void DeleteBook()
{
    NODE *temp=head;
    head = head->next;
    free(temp);
    temp=NULL;
}
void DeleteIssues()
{
    NODE *temp=issuehead;
    issuehead = issuehead->next;
    free(temp);
    temp=NULL;
}
void AcceptData(BOOK *book)
{
    book->bookId=++counter;
    getchar();
    printf(" Enter Book name::");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",&book->bookName);
    getchar();
    printf(" Enter Subject::");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",&book->subject);
    getchar();
    printf(" Enter author::");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",&book->author);
    printf(" Enter price::");
    scanf("%f",&book->price);
}
void DisplayData(BOOK book)
{
    printf(" %d\t\t",book.bookId);
    printf(" %s\t\t",book.bookName);
    printf(" %s\t\t",book.subject);
    printf(" %s\t\t",book.author);
    printf(" %g\n",book.price);
}
NODE *CreateNode()
{
    NODE *temp;
    temp = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    temp->next=NULL;
    temp->prev=NULL;
    return temp;
}
void AddtoBooklist(BOOK book)
{
    NODE *new_node;
    new_node=CreateNode();
    new_node->info=book;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head=new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        new_node->next=head;
        head->prev=new_node;
        head=new_node;
    }
}
void DisplayBooks(NODE *trav)
{
    if(trav==NULL)
    {
        printf(" Book list is empty...\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" Available Books\n");
        while(trav!=NULL)
        {
            DisplayData(trav->info);
            trav=trav->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void IssueBook()
{
    NODE *trav=head, *prev=NULL;
    NODE *temp, *right;
    int bookId;
    printf(" Enter Book ID::");
    scanf("%d",&bookId);
    while(bookId != trav->info.bookId)
    {
        prev=trav;
        trav=trav->next;
        if(trav==NULL)
        {
            printf(" Book not found...\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    if(trav==head)
    {
        temp = trav;
        head->prev=NULL;
        head = head->next;
        trav=NULL;
        IssueAtFirst(temp);
        printf(" Book issued successfully...\n");
    }
    else if(trav->next==NULL)
    {
        temp=trav;
        prev->next=NULL;
        trav->prev=NULL;
        trav=NULL;
        IssueAtFirst(temp);
        printf(" Book issued successfully...\n");
    }
    else
    {
        temp=trav;
        right=trav->next;
        prev->next=right;
        right->prev=prev;
        trav->next=NULL;
        trav->prev=NULL;
        trav=NULL;
        IssueAtFirst(temp);
        printf(" Book issued successfully...\n");
    }
}
void IssueAtFirst(NODE *temp)
{
    if(issuehead == NULL)
    {
        issuehead=temp;
        temp->next=NULL;
        temp->prev=NULL;
        temp=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next=issuehead;
        temp->prev=NULL;
        issuehead=temp;
        temp=NULL;
    }
}
void ReturnBook()
{
    NODE *trav=issuehead, *prev=NULL;
    NODE *temp, *right;
    int bookId;
    printf(" Enter Book ID::");
    scanf("%d",&bookId);
    while(bookId != trav->info.bookId)
    {
        prev=trav;
        trav=trav->next;
        if(trav==NULL)
        {
            printf(" Book not found...\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    if(trav==issuehead)
    {
        temp = trav;
        issuehead->prev = NULL;
        issuehead = issuehead->next;
        trav=NULL;
        ReturnAtFirst(temp);
        printf(" Book returned successfully...\n");
    }
    else if(trav->next==NULL)
    {
        temp=trav;
        prev->next=NULL;
        trav->prev=NULL;
        trav=NULL;
        ReturnAtFirst(temp);
        printf(" Book returned successfully...\n");
    }
    else
    {
        temp=trav;
        right=trav->next;
        prev->next=right;
        right->prev=prev;
        trav->next=NULL;
        trav->prev=NULL;
        trav=NULL;
        ReturnAtFirst(temp);
        printf(" Book returned successfully...\n");
    }
}
void ReturnAtFirst(NODE *temp)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
        temp->next=NULL;
        temp->prev=NULL;
        temp=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        head->prev=temp;
        temp->next=head;
        temp->prev=NULL;
        head=temp;
        temp=NULL;
    }
}
void SortBooks()
{
    NODE *trav=head,*right=head->next;
    BOOK temp;
    while(trav->next!=NULL)
    {
        right=trav->next;
        while(right!=NULL)
        {
            if(trav->info.bookId > right->info.bookId)
            {
                temp = trav->info;
                trav->info = right->info;
                right->info = temp;
            }
            right=right->next;
        }
        trav=trav->next;
    }
}
void AddBooksToFile()
{
    NODE *trav=head;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("Booklist.dat","wb");
    if(fp!=NULL)
    {
        while(trav!=NULL)
        {
            fwrite(&trav->info, sizeof(BOOK),1,fp);
            trav=trav->next;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
void AddIssuesToFile()
{
    NODE *trav=issuehead;
    FILE *fp=issuehead;
    fp=fopen("Issuelist.dat","wb");
    if(fp!=NULL)
    {
        while(trav!=NULL)
        {
            fwrite(&trav->info, sizeof(BOOK),1,fp);
            trav=trav->next;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
void ReadIssuesFromFile()
{
    BOOK book;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("Issuelist.dat","rb");
    if(fp!=NULL)
    {
        while((fread(&book,sizeof(BOOK),1,fp))!=0)
        {
            AddtoIssuelist(book);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
void ReadBooksFromFile()
{
    BOOK book;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("Booklist.dat","rb");
    if(fp!=NULL)
    {
        while((fread(&book,sizeof(BOOK),1,fp))!=0)
        {
            AddtoBooklist(book);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
void AddtoIssuelist(BOOK book)
{
    NODE *new_node;
    new_node=CreateNode();
    new_node->info=book;
    if(issuehead == NULL)
    {
        issuehead=new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        new_node->next=issuehead;
        issuehead->prev=new_node;
        issuehead=new_node;
    }
}
void DisplaySubjectWise(NODE *head)
{
    NODE *trav=head;
    char subject[30];
    printf(" Enter subject::");
    scanf("%s",&subject);
    while(trav!=NULL)
    {
        if(stricmp(subject, trav->info.subject)== 0)
        {
            DisplayData(trav->info);
        }
        trav=trav->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    MENU choice;
    int data;
    BOOK book;
    ReadBooksFromFile();
    ReadIssuesFromFile();
    while((choice=menu_function())!=EXIT)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
        case ADD_BOOK:
            AcceptData(&book);
            AddtoBooklist(book);
            printf(" Book added to library successfully...\n");
            break;
        case ISSUE_BOOK:
            if(head==NULL)
            {
                printf(" No Books are available now...\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                IssueBook();
            }
            break;
        case RETURN_BOOK:
            if(issuehead==NULL)
            {
                printf(" No Books are issued...\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                ReturnBook();
            }
            break;
        case DISPLAY_BOOKS:
            DisplayBooks(head);
            DisplayBooks(issuehead);
            printf("\n");
            break;
        case SORT_BOOKS:
            if(head==NULL)
            {
                printf(" No Books to sort...\n");
                break;
            }
            SortBooks();
            break;
        case DISPLAY_BOOK_SUBJECTWISE:
            if(head==NULL)
            {
                printf(" No Books to display...\n");
                break;
            }
            DisplaySubjectWise(head);
            break;
        }
    }
    AddBooksToFile();
    AddIssuesToFile();
    FreeList();
    return 0;
}
```

for your reference